# Function Pointer

Tags: function-pointers

How is that function pointer better than if-else or switch case? Is it because function pointer helps callback functions and thus promotes asynchronous implementation?

Comment: You may want to mention the language you are refering to.

Comment: Why, what difference would knowing the language make?

Comment: Better in what context?  It's not better for writing conditionals or switches...

Answer (score 2):

It's better if the functions are not known beforehand.  How would you design the C standard library `qsort()` without using a function pointer?

Comment: "if the functions are not known beforehand" that is a key point. I just wanted to emphasize it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not "better", it's different. Yes, the main purpose of function pointer is to provide callback functionality. No, it is not directly related to asynchronism.

Check [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) for more information on function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

According to Nigel Jones, it improves code readability, among others

http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2010/04/efficient-c-tip-12-be-wary-of-switch-statements/

He even provides some examples:

http://www.rmbconsulting.us/Publications/jump-Tables.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Function pointers result in a better design of your code. Consider when you have an option of calling one function out of fifty functions. How massive would the switch case be? However, you could easily map all the function pointers as per their id, and call the appropriate function from the map using the "id". The code would be easily maintained and look neat.

There are other benefits and powers of using function pointer.
For a good explanation, look at the tutorial [here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html)

Comment: Also, you have complexity guarantees in using a map you wouldn't have in a switch-case. The compiler may not always be able to build a jump table, case where the search for the right function to be called would be sequential. In a map the search would be a very fast O(log N), with a binary tree, or O(1) in a hash map.